# MplayerCtrl - MPlayer on Mac with WxPython

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, wxpython, mplayer

I am trying to get a simple media player working (scipt below) on Python 2.7.11, Wxpython, with MplayerCtrl on Mac 10.11.4, I just compiled the latest MPlayer 1.3.0, but when opening an mp4 video file I get the below error message, Mplayer opens independently (not in the player window) and also XQuartz opens for some reason, heres the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Python/MediaPlayer/mediaplayer.py", line 124, in on_add_file
    self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_controls.py", line 2866, in SetRange
    return _controls_.Slider_SetRange(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'Slider_SetRange', expected argument 3 of type 'int'
```

I have MPlayer 1.3.0 in the same directory as the .py script.

Here is the script I am using:

```
import os
import time
import wx
import MplayerCtrl as mpc
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
bitmapDir = os.path.join(dirName, 'bitmaps')

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, mplayer):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sp = wx.StandardPaths.Get()
        self.currentFolder = sp.GetDocumentsDir()
        self.currentVolume = 50

        self.create_menu()

        # create sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        controlSizer = self.build_controls()
        sliderSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.mplayer = mpc.MplayerCtrl(self.panel, -1, mplayer)
        self.playbackSlider = wx.Slider(self.panel, size=wx.DefaultSize)
        sliderSizer.Add(self.playbackSlider, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # create volume control
        self.volumeCtrl = wx.Slider(self.panel)
        self.volumeCtrl.SetRange(0, 100)
        self.volumeCtrl.SetValue(self.currentVolume)
        self.volumeCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.on_set_volume)
        controlSizer.Add(self.volumeCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # create track counter
        self.trackCounter = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="00:00")
        sliderSizer.Add(self.trackCounter, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        # set up playback timer
        self.playbackTimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_update_playback)

        mainSizer.Add(self.mplayer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(sliderSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(controlSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)

        self.Bind(mpc.EVT_MEDIA_STARTED, self.on_media_started)
        self.Bind(mpc.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.on_media_finished)
        self.Bind(mpc.EVT_PROCESS_STARTED, self.on_process_started)
        self.Bind(mpc.EVT_PROCESS_STOPPED, self.on_process_stopped)

        self.Show()
        self.panel.Layout()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def build_btn(self, btnDict, sizer):
        """"""
        bmp = btnDict['bitmap']
        handler = btnDict['handler']

        img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, bmp))
        btn = buttons.GenBitmapButton(self.panel, bitmap=img,
                                      name=btnDict['name'])
        btn.SetInitialSize()
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.LEFT, 3)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def build_controls(self):
        """
        Builds the audio bar controls
        """
        controlSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        btnData = [{'bitmap':'player_pause.png', 
                    'handler':self.on_pause, 'name':'pause'},
                   {'bitmap':'player_stop.png',
                    'handler':self.on_stop, 'name':'stop'}]
        for btn in btnData:
            self.build_btn(btn, controlSizer)

        return controlSizer

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_menu(self):
        """
        Creates a menu
        """
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        add_file_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&Add File", "Add Media File")
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_add_file, add_file_menu_item)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_add_file(self, event):
        """
        Add a Movie and start playing it
        """
        wildcard = "Media Files (*.*)|*.*"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Choose a file",
            defaultDir=self.currentFolder, 
            defaultFile="",
            wildcard=wildcard,
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.currentFolder = os.path.dirname(path[0])
            trackPath = '"%s"' % path.replace("\\", "/")
            self.mplayer.Loadfile(trackPath)

            t_len = self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()
            self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
            self.playbackTimer.Start(100)


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_media_started(self, event):
        print 'Media started!'

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_media_finished(self, event):
        print 'Media finished!'
        self.playbackTimer.Stop()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_pause(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.playbackTimer.IsRunning():
            print "pausing..."
            self.mplayer.Pause()
            self.playbackTimer.Stop()
        else:
            print "unpausing..."
            self.mplayer.Pause()
            self.playbackTimer.Start()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_process_started(self, event):
        print 'Process started!'

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_process_stopped(self, event):
        print 'Process stopped!'

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_set_volume(self, event):
        """
        Sets the volume of the music player
        """
        self.currentVolume = self.volumeCtrl.GetValue()
        self.mplayer.SetProperty("volume", self.currentVolume)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_stop(self, event):
        """"""
        print "stopping..."
        self.mplayer.Stop()
        self.playbackTimer.Stop()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_update_playback(self, event):
        """
        Updates playback slider and track counter
        """
        try:
            offset = self.mplayer.GetTimePos()
        except:
            return
        print offset
        mod_off = str(offset)[-1]
        if mod_off == '0':
            print "mod_off"
            offset = int(offset)
            self.playbackSlider.SetValue(offset)
            secsPlayed = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(offset))
            self.trackCounter.SetLabel(secsPlayed)        

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os, sys

    paths = [r'./mplayer',
             r'./mplayer']
    mplayerPath = None
    for path in paths:
        if os.path.exists(path):
            mplayerPath = path

    if not mplayerPath:
        print "mplayer not found!"
        sys.exit()

    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = Frame(None, -1, 'MediaPlayer Using MplayerCtrl', mplayerPath)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am keen on using MPlayer for its flexibility.

Comment: That error message is not even in your script, so you'll need to find where it is... And when you say it's running, how is it running? Did you use `Start()` as instructed?

Comment: I have tried using self.mplayer.Start() but still gives me the error.